SwiftUI Customize Tip that is popoverTip
enter image description here
Hi, i'm using tipKit - popoverTip, from the box it uses some kind of Color.secondary for backGround. But i need customize the background color of the tip in popoverTip.
Is it possible to customize tip, that is popoverTip type?
I found, that i could change foreground color of each element, but is doesn't work to change the back ground of the tip.
TipView looks different, and is not appropriate here

Use TipViewStyle to customize tips.

struct CustomTipViewStyle: TipViewStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: TipViewStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                configuration.image?
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)


                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
                    configuration.title?
                        .font(.headline)
                    configuration.message?
                        .font(.subheadline)

                    ForEach(configuration.actions) { action in
                        Button(action: action.handler) {
                            action.label().foregroundStyle(.blue)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Button(action: { configuration.tip.invalidate(reason: .tipClosed) }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark").scaledToFit()
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.indigo)
    }
}

struct PopoverTip: Tip {
    var title: Text {
        Text("Write what you want")
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
    var message: Text? {
        Text("And our AI will create an unique image for you")
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
    var image: Image? {
        Image(systemName: "wand.and.stars")
    }
}

struct TipKitView: View {
    let popoverTip = PopoverTip()
    @State private var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter your name", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .popoverTip(popoverTip)
                .onTapGesture {
                    popoverTip.invalidate(reason: .actionPerformed)
                }
                .tipViewStyle(CustomTipViewStyle())
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

